# How to combine a RegEx expression so it will match . - \ spaces and no spaces zeros and upper and lower case letters

Tags: regex

I have the group of numbers...does anybody know a RegEx that will match and combine the following:

```
BG18.RZBB.9155.0123.4567
BG18 RZBB 9155 0123 4567 
BG18RZBB91550123456789
BG18-RZBB-9155-0123-4567
```

@DavidPostil I really do not know how to explain it any clearer.   I am just trying to write an REGEX where I can combine those numbers or dots, hyphens, spaces an no spaces lower case letters and zeros.  I will add in test string in REGEx101 run the expression and I should get a match.

My effort is as follows:

```
BG\d{2}[ -.]\d{4}[ -.]\d{3}[ -.]\d{4}[ -.]\d{4|\bCH\d{22}\b
```

Comment: You need to work on explaining your questions. What exactly do you mean by "match and combine".

Comment: I suggest you go and read  - [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
 - [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
 - [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
 - [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)

Comment: @DavidPostill---I have four groups of numbers   BG18.RZBB.9155.0123.4567
BG18 RZBB 9155 0123 4567
BG18RZBB91550123456789
BG18-RZBB-9155-0123-4567   I need a regualr expression that will match when I run in Regex101 and that will combine the four group of numbers   I have tried BE\d{2}[ -.]\d{4}[ -.]\d{3}[ -.]\d{4}[ -.]\d{4|\bBE\d{22}\b   I will read the tutorials per your request   ty

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show exactly what you expect the **output** to be for each of the **inputs**

Comment: Regular expressions match strings (i.e., sequences of characters, or blocks of text); they do not change the text strings (e.g., combine them).  To do that, you need a tool — a command / program / utility.  Do you have one in mind?  What is is?  (Hint: Notepad++ and `sed` are a couple of your options.)  Please do not reply in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @Toto: Please be more careful when you edit.  (1) The OP said “as follows”, which is correct, and you incorrectly changed it.  (2) We prefer that, when you edit a post (and especially when you, as a <2K user, *suggest* an edit), you make all the changes that need to be made.  This post had many problems, and you fixed only a couple of them.

Comment: @Scott: OK, I've just took care of formatting and the sentence just before the regex. My bad I've deleted an `s`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Davidpostill says your question requires more clarification because it depends on programming/scripting language. 
But if you used it over regex101.com as online.
I copied this in input box.

```
G18.RZBB.9155.0123.4567

BG18 RZBB 9155 0123 4567

BG18RZBB91550123456789

BG18-RZBB-9155-0123-4567
```

And entered your regular expression with some modification.

```
B*G\d{2}[ -.]\w{4}[ -.]\d{4}[ -.]\d{4}[ -.](\d{4})
```

I think when you talk about combine you probably want to make them as back reference. In this circumstance you need parenthesis.

Explaination:

`B*`, string contains "B" char zero or more times.

`G`,  string follows with exact "G" char only one time.

`\d{2}`, string follows with 2 digits(0-9)

`[ -.]`,  string follows with any of those char in square parantheses. (**" ", "-". "."**)

**..........**

`(\d{4})`, finally string follows with 4 digits. And group this to access it in replace field.

So you can access last 4 digits in replace field only typing "**$1**" (without quotes).

It won't match only this line

```
BG18RZBB91550123456789
```

Because after **"B*G\d{2}"** this part of regex it must follow with any of character **" ", "-", "."** so it breaks the matches in this step